# how to make a dialog(or a view or something else) lie in front of the page of any app?

Tags: android, user-interface

i want to program an Android app, once the app is opened, it will generate an UI(something like a dialog and in this dialog, it will show video pictures which are pushed by a server),  and this would always be lieing in front of the UI of other apps, however i don't know whether this idea can be realized, and if it could be, the possible steps could be what, hoping someone can give me some clues or demo code or app, thanks in advance.

EDIT1:my mistake, yep, i do want to it looks like an dialog, but the most important thins is that:`i just want to this so-called dialog showing in the front of other app's UI`, or i can just explain it like this: `once this dialog appears, it will still be showing in the screen no matter you open another app or doing something else, this dialog could only be closed by force that means you could not close the dialog by exit the app`

EDIT2:yeah, i find that similar function in galaxy SIII and galaxy Notes II's video player, it is called `PIP(Picture in Picture)` or `Pop up play`

Comment: Is this a good idea? I would immediately uninstall such an app.

Comment: yep, i can't agree with you more. however, this is just the meaning of my leader

Answer (score 1):

The idea / trick is to make an `Activity` where you will be running all your code to fetch and display the video and make it look like a **`Dialog`**

Since this is more about the UI, regardless of what is being done in the Activity, setting it up in the Manifest, for example, like this should do what you need it to do:

```
<activity
    android:name="ACTIVITY_NAME"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
</activity>
```

If you need the entire application to look like a Dialog, you will need to set the `android:theme` attribute to the `<application></application>` instead of setting it to the `Activity`

You would probably want to customize it instead of using the *stock Dialog Theme*.

These should get you started:

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
2. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html
3. http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_ui_themes-t4367.html

**UPDATE**

The Android OS reserves the right to close any application if and when the system becomes low on resources or a *user chooses too*. Short of ***perhaps*** building your own custom OS, I am not sure there are any options available for such a task. Plus, as *Henry* has already commented, this may not be a good option to *force something* on your app's users. You may have a specific requirement from a client or something to that effect, but perhaps you may want to revisit that specification.

Comment: thanks, Siddharth. but i think you do not figure out the real problem i refer to, maybe, it's my poor english's fault, :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show your app like a dialog, you can set

```
 <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

in your manifest.